# How do I run a specific shell script in a cron job?

Tags: oracle, csv, cron, cron-task

I have set up a cron job which will run a shell script to connect to our Oracle database and copy a table as a csv file.

crontab -l outputs:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/user/import.sh > /home/user/importLog.txt
```

import.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="/path/to/application/TABLE.csv"

sqlplus -s user/pw@db <<EOF

SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET COLSEP ","
SET LINESIZE 200
SET FEEDBACK OFF

SPOOL $FILE

SELECT * FROM TABLENAME;

SPOOL OFF
EXIT
EOF
```

Now, when I run import.sh manually, it successfully imports the table and creates the csv file, whereas the cron job seems to run, as it generates importLog.txt(which is blank), but it does not ever create a csv file.

Comment: just a guess, but have u tried redirecting stderr also?  import.sh > import.log 2>&1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cron jobs run with a very "impoverished" environment.  You might need to set up environment variables to locate your `tnsnames` config files.  You're also expecting `sqlplus` to be on the command path, which it may not be if you haven't set it up in the crontab previously -- I highly recommend putting the full path to the sqlplus binary in your script.  Finally, add

```
MAILTO=your@email.addr
```

early on in your crontab to make sure you get an email with the error notification (assuming your sendmail config is set up correctly).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to redirecting stderr to your logfile

```
import.sh > import.log 2>&1
```

Note: if you want a running log (append), then:

```
import.sh >> import.log 2>&1
```

You will probably want to add 
    **whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode** 
in your shell script to make sure you capture the error:

```
sqlplus -s user/password << EOF
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;

...
EOF
```

*Using Mail and Logs*

If you want to redirect both stdout and stderr to both a logfile and to mail, you can do this on most *nix systems:

```
* * * * * /path/to/import.sh 2>&1 | tee -a /path/to/import.log | mail -s "Output of import.sh" someuser@someaddr.com
```

This way you have both a running logfile and a email alert (of stderr and stdout).  You can also setup different logfiles and/or email addresses for each script in the crontab if desired.

Comment: If you follow the stderr redirect advice, the `MAILTO` part of cron won't automatically mail you the error message if something goes sideways -- you'll have to check the log manually.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer Hi, the OP was already redirecting to a logfile, I just added the redirect of stderr to the logfile.  If mail is desired over a logfile, each crontab entry can pipe stdout (and stderr) to mail command (with potentially different email recipients/subjects, etc for each cron entry)

Comment: */5 * * * * /path/to/import.sh 2>&1 | mail -s "Output of import.sh" toaddress@example.com